# Sort Excel by a pattern

Tags: excel, string, date, design-patterns

I have a list of people, it is one cell only, comprising last,first, birth/death dates(xxxx-) or (xxxx-xxxx), and brief descriptions.

Sample data:

```
Jones,Bob,(03012018-),Description
Rod,Axle,(01121980-12312012),Description
```

I want to sort by those living, i.e. filter out those birth/death dates that have a number after the dash(xxxx-xxxx).

Desired output:

```
Jones,Bob,(03012018-),Description
```

I think this should be easy, but am hardly an excel guru....

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you get your data from ? In theory, Excel should automatically separate in different cells. Isnt your Excel in English ? Maybe you could just use the function "From Text/CSV". => Data => PANEL : Get & Transform Data => From Text/CSV. Choose your file and use the delimiter "comma". If your Excel is not in english, it is possible that "comma" is not by default chosen.

After that, you can just create a table and order your data as you want.